# Vuex store state is undefined

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to use `Vuex ("^2.1.3")` with `vuejs ("^2.1.10")` project in this way:

store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        inTheaters: [
            {
                name: 'Resident Evil: The Final Chapter',
                poster_url: 'https://blackgirlnerds.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Resident-Evil-The-Final-Chapter-Final-Poster-Featured.jpg',
                language: 'English',
            },
            {
                name: 'Irada',
                poster_url: 'http://filmywave.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/irada-movie-poster-1.jpg',
                language: 'Hindi',
            },
        ]
    },
});
```

main.js:

```
import store from './store';

new Vue({
    router,
    components: {App},
    template: '<App/>',
    store,
}).$mount('#app');
```

some-component.js:

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'movieListWrapper',
        props: {
            movieListType: {
                type: String,
                default: 'in-theateras',
            },
        },
        computed: {
            movieList() {
                return this.$store.state.inTheaters;
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

I now have two problems:

1. First is I get a warning in my console

> "export 'default' (imported as 'store') was not found in './store'

2. The other problem is that the `state` is not defined.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

I am very new to this and may be I am missing some thing so please pardon me. What am I missing?

Comment: try `export default new Vuex.Store({` instead of `export const store = new Vuex.Store({` in your store.js maybe?

Comment: Or `import {store} from './store';`

Comment: Yes! I tried both way, and both worked out to be the answer. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your store.js:

`export default new Vuex.Store({` instead of `export const store = new Vuex.Store({`

Or as @dfsq said `import {store} from './store';`

Answer (score 2):

//state.js

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({

    state :{
         title :"Welcome in Vuex Tutorials By SK Islam"
    }

});
```

Then in main.js please import the store in this way..

```
import {store} from "./store/state";
```

{store}// this is important..